# Nautilus: change "paste" to auto-check copied file against original

Tags: nautilus, diff, paste

Is it somehow possible (maybe with nautilus actions?) to change the behaviour of the "paste" functionality or to add a new paste functionality that does the following:

- paste as normal
- do a diff of original and copy
- show the results of diff

Any ideas?

Thank you!